# Can't request Azure Resource Manager from c# MVC application

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-resource-manager

I am developing an MVC application that should get informations about all Azure Resource an authenticated user have.

I perform the authentication part from the Visual Studio Wizzard in Multiple  Organizations mode.

So I connect against: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common

Now I need to get the access token from a controller of the application.
I tried to get the authentication token from that code:

```
   ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _servicePrincipalPassword);

   AuthenticationContext context = new 
   AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
   var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc);
   return result.AccessToken;
```

I get a token, but when using it I receive an InvalidAuthenticationToken.
My token lack one of these claims: 'puid', 'altsecid' or 'oid'.

I don't know what to do and need some help.
I am pretty sure having this code working a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I am developing an MVC application that should get informations about all Azure Resource an authenticated user have.

According to your code , you are using client credential flow to authenticate with app identity , authenticating as the app means there is no user involved. To achive your requirement , you could use [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) . [Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect) is a code sample how to build multi-tenant SaaS web application that calls a web API using Azure AD .

In [Startup.Auth.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) of the code sample , `AuthorizationCodeReceived` notification could be used to acquire token for ARM rest api . `SecurityTokenValidated` notification  contains the custom caller validation logic.